# postgres container does not has home

Tags: postgresql, ssh

I want to let `postgres` user execute `shell_scritp.sh`
My container is `postgres`. Then I have to put my initialization script in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`
Everything in this directory will be execute by `postgres` user. 
It is just fine. If that file is `sql` and execute by `postgres` owner

The problem raises when I have to let `postgres` do `ssh tunnelling, pg_dump, and pg_restore` from production server to container.

The container raises `postgres` has no home `/home/postgres/.ssh`

I had tried let `root` users execute that script. It raises `permission denied` when `root` is about to create database.

Right now I workaround by hand. 
What is the best practice on this?

Comment: Is the container running on the production server? If so just exec into the container and run the commands.

Comment: No. This is on development. That is why I want to let `postgres` container automates everything for me. Therefore I can let my colleagues smoothly start dev and debug instead me easily.